# How to create a table layout like this

Tags: html, css

am trying to create a table layout like this:

```html
<img src='data:image/png;base64,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'/>
```

So far I achive this:

```
<table class="table">
   <tr>
      <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">INCOME</th>
      <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">EXPENSE</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>30,000</td>
      <td>100,000</td>
      <td>80,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5,000</td>
      <td>12,000</td>
      <td>9,000</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Can anybody try to help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```html
<table class="table" width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
   <tr>
      <th width="50%" colspan="2">INCOME</th>
      <th width="50%" colspan="2">EXPENSE</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="25%">Name A</td>
      <td width="25%"><center>10,000</center></td>
      <td width="25%">Name A</td>
      <td width="25%"><center>5,000</center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="25%">Name B</td>
      <td width="25%"><center>10,000</center></td>
      <td width="25%">Name B</td>
      <td width="25%"><center>5,000</center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="25%"><center><b>Total</b></center></td>
      <td width="25%"><center>20,000</center></td>
      <td width="25%"><center><b>Total</b></center></td>
      <td width="25%"><center>10,000</center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th width="50%" colspan="2">money start</th>
      <th width="50%" colspan="2">1,000.00</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th width="50%" colspan="2">daily money</th>
      <th width="50%" colspan="2">10,00</th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="50%" colspan="2">overall</th>
      <th width="50%" colspan="2">1.010,00</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this html markup help you?

```html
  <table class="table" border=2>
       <tr>
          <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">INCOME</th>
          <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">EXPENSE</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Name A</td>
          <td>10,00</td>
          <td>name b</td>
          <td>10,00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Name A</td>
          <td>5,00</td>
          <td>Name B</td>
          <td>5,00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>TOTAL:</td>
          <td>20,00</td>
          <td>TOTAL:</td>
          <td>10,00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Money start</td>
          <td colspan="2">1.000,00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Daily money</td>
          <td colspan="2">10,00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Overall</td>
          <td colspan="2">1.010,00</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```